# Spring Social Redirect Flow

Tags: facebook, spring, spring-boot, spring-social

Is there a way to do flow like this in Spring Social?

1. Not logged user opens /me (`Facebook#isAuthorized() == false`)
2. Server redirects user to facebook login (skips /connect/facebookConnect)
3. User use his credentials in fb login
4. Facebook redirects back to /me (skips /connect/facebookConnected)

I don't want to set `ConnectController#setApplicationUrl`, because I want to use different callbacks for other OAuth providers.

**EDIT**:

Ok, using `SocialAuthenticationFilter` with proper `/signup` and `/signin` controller does the trick.

Comment: You have described what you would like to achieve. What is the behavior that you are getting at this time?

Comment: The default behaviour looks like this: 1. You open '/me' and it redirects to '/connect/facebook' where is a button "login to facebook" (or sth like this). 2. after button has been clicked (which makes POST call to '/connect/facebook'), you are beign redirected to facebook login screen. 3. after login and accept application in facebook site, it redirects you back to '/connect/facebook' and from here you can go to '/me' endpoint. I want to skip '/connect/facebook' steps ( or at least first one, this spring-generated site with button).